# How to deduce the return type of a function which takes a reference as parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, decltype, return-type-deduction

I am trying to deduce the return type of a function and use it as return type of a member function. For this I am using a decltype expression. But all my attempts fail to compile if the given function takes a reference as argument:

- I cannot use any member variables of my class in the decltype expression, because the compiler complains that there are no such members (see `func1` below)
- I cannot use a temporary for the function parameter, since the function takes a reference and you cannot bind a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary (see `func2` below)

I also tried various casting operators to make the reference take the temporary, but nothing seems to be a valid expression.

Here a code example:

```
template<typename data_type, typename functor_type>
class MyClass
{
public:
    auto func1() -> decltype(functor_type::process(this->m_data)) // <--
    {
        return functor_type::process(m_data);
    }

    auto func2() -> decltype(functor_type::process(data_type{})) // <--
    {
        return functor_type::process(m_data);
    }

private:
    data_type m_data;
};

struct Functor
{
    static int process(int& a) { return a; }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int, Functor> m;
    int b = m.func1();
    int c = m.func2();
}
```

Comment: For `func1` one to work, move the declaration of `m_data` before it. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53dcd44b0bc75005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first fails because the class is not complete in the function declaration, as it is in member function bodies, so you can only use members that have already been declared.

For the second, the standard library provides `declval`, a function template declared to return its template parameter type. You can use this in unevaluated contexts when you need an expression of a particular type.

So the following version should work:

```
#include <utility> // for declval

template<typename data_type, typename functor_type>
class MyClass
{
private:
    // Declare this before `func1`
    data_type m_data;

public:
    // Use the already declared member variable
    auto func1() -> decltype(functor_type::process(m_data))
    {
        return functor_type::process(m_data);
    }

    // Or use `declval` to get an expression with the required reference type
    auto func2() -> decltype(functor_type::process(std::declval<data_type&>()))
    {
        return functor_type::process(m_data);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for `std::declval<data_type&>()`